# Adding a different sized, independent, table under another with same caption

Tags: tables, formatting

I am working on a paper and I need to add a different sized, independent, table under another with the same caption.
I have tried and tried but nothing works.

I have made a small, but complete, example of what I have so far:

```
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage{graphicx} %include pictures
\usepackage{float} % include advanced picture manipulation

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths


\begin{document}

Some text up here...
\begin{table}[H]
\tiny
%\caption{Global caption}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on left side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
  0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  2 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 5 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Caption A.}
\label{tab:tableA}
\end{minipage}%
%\end{table}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on right side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
  1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  3 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & 1 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}%
\caption{Caption B.}
\label{tab:tableB}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}

Some other text down here..

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: The result I have now.]

These are confusion matrices.

Anyways, What I am trying to do is to show two more tables under each of them. So the end result should look something like this:

[image: The result that I want to get.]

I have tried a lot of different stuff but it always manages to show in some weird way like on the side and over the other table.
I am getting very frustrated about this issue so I hope that someone can help me with this.
Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the table I want to show under the previous tables:

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Your example is far from minimal. Please add the table, you try to add here, to your question. What stuff have you tried? We do not want to do the same errors again. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to have a global caption above all of this?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I edited the question to include the table. I have tried to use the \multicolumn and \multirow without success.
I don't want a global caption.
These are supposed to be two tables (on the left side and the right), each with two tables (top and bottom). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What happens when you put the `tabular` code inside the same `minipage` just after the `\scalebox` closure *and* leave an empty/blank line inbetween?

Comment: If I do that then they are aligned horizontally and it will appear on the left side of the bigger table.
Tried that also :)

Comment: @Sigmundur: Then you didn't leave a blank line between them as I suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `tabular` underneath the `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage{graphicx} %include pictures
\usepackage{float} % include advanced picture manipulation

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths


\begin{document}

Some text up here...
\begin{table}[H]
\tiny
%\caption{Global caption}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on left side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline
  0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  2 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 5 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

%\medskip %% some extra space if needed
\scalebox{0.75}{%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Caption A.}
\label{tab:tableA}
\end{minipage}%
%\end{table}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on right side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline
  1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  3 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & 1 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}%

%\medskip %% some extra space if needed
 \scalebox{0.75}{%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Caption B.}
\label{tab:tableB}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}

Some other text down here..

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one works for some reason. I thought I tried this before. I must have done it in a slightly different way or something.
I will use this one for now and if I get no problems with it then I will accept the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: @Sigmundur You need that blank line in between the bigger and smaller tabulars (just before `%\medskip %% some extra space if needed`). If not they go side by side.

Comment: I see. 
That is a very subtle thing :)  I have a feeling that this blank line was the culprit when I tried a similar thing. But it is working now, thanks to you. I will mark this as the correct answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
Some text up here...
\begin{table}[H]
    \tiny
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.8}{
            \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
                \hline 
                a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & \text{- Classified as}\\ \hline
                \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
                0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
                2 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 5 & h = 8\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & i = 9\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.8}{
            \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
                \hline 
                a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & \text{- Classified as}\\ \hline
                \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
                1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
                3 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & 1 & h = 8\\ \hline
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & i = 9\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    \end{minipage}\baselineskip2cm
%%% leave one line free

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
        \hline 
            a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption A.}
        \label{tab:tableA}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
            \hline 
            a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption B.}
        \label{tab:tableB}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{table}

Some other text down here..
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or nicer with booktabs:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
Some text up here\dots
\begin{table}[H]
    \tiny
    \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{.6ex}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.85}{
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{>{$}c<{$}}}
                \toprule 
                a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & \text{- Classified as}\\ \midrule
                \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\  
                0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ 
                0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c = 3\\ 
                2 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & d = 4\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f = 6\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ 
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 5 & h = 8\\ 
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & i = 9\\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.85}{
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{>{$}c<{$}}}
                \toprule 
                a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & \text{- Classified as}\\ \midrule
                \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\  
                1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ 
                3 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & c = 3\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & d = 4\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & f = 6\\ 
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & 1 & h = 8\\ 
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & i = 9\\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    \end{minipage}\baselineskip2.1cm
%%% leave one line free

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
        \scalebox{0.85}{
        \begin{tabular}{*{6}{>{$}c<{$}}}
        \toprule 
            a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \midrule
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
        \caption{Caption A.}
        \label{tab:tableA}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
        \scalebox{0.85}{
        \begin{tabular}{*{6}{>{$}c<{$}}}
            \toprule 
            a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \midrule
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
        \caption{Caption B.}
        \label{tab:tableB}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{table}

Some other text down here\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stack it!

```
% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\usepackage{graphicx} %include pictures
\usepackage{float} % include advanced picture manipulation

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

Some text up here...
\begin{table}[H]
\tiny
%\caption{Global caption}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on left side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\stackunder[6pt]{
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
  0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  2 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}5 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 5 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Caption A.}
\label{tab:tableA}
\end{minipage}%
%\end{table}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
% Table on right side
%\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\stackunder[6pt]{
\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & - Classified as\\ \hline
  \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a = 1\\ \hline 
  1 & \cellcolor{blue!25}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b = 2\\ \hline
  3 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & c = 3\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & d = 4\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & e = 5\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & f = 6\\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}4 & 0 & 0 & g = 7\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}3 & 1 & h = 8\\ \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{blue!25}6 & i = 9\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}%
}{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline 
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Caption B.}
\label{tab:tableB}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}

Some other text down here..

\end{document}
```

[image]